# Custom handler not getting triggered

Tags: sitecore-api

I have a custom handler in my code (Sitecore 9.3). In the web.config:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="JFSRedirect" verb="*" path="JFSRedirect.axd" type="Site.Feature.Journals.Handlers.JfsAuthenticationHandler, Site.Feature.Journals" />
```

The handler code

```
namespace Site.Feature.Journals.Handlers
{
    public class JfsAuthenticationHandler: IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Log.Info("JfsAuthenticationHandler - Processing", this);
.....
```

However it doesn't get triggered when it's supposed to. I land on this URL, which you can see contains the path "JFSRedirect.axd":

`https://site.erica.velir.sc/news-and-publications/scientific-journals?nextUrl=https%3a%2f%2fsite.erica.velir.sc%2fjfsredirect.axd%3farticle%3dhttps%3a%2f%2fjournals.com%2fjournal%2f17503841`

Am I missing something in the configuration, or is my URL incorrect for triggering the handler?

Comment: You're missing wildcards in the path config, but even then I think the path in the config is your actual path and not the querystring. You could try to fetch all requests and test the path in the code.

Comment: Explanation, what @Gatogordo said about the path 
The path that IIS tries to match is https://site.erica.velir.sc/news-and-publications/scientific-journals. It doesn't match JFSRedirect.axd. That is why it would not be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, the path does not include your querystring - and is missing wildcard(s).

If you want to intercept all urls with JFSRedirect.axd in the querystring, you'll need to put "*" in the path config like this:

```
<add name="JFSRedirect" verb="*" path="*" type="Site.Feature.Journals.Handlers.JfsAuthenticationHandler, Site.Feature.Journals" />
```

In your code, you can check the querystring for "JFSRedirect.axd" and get out if you can't find it. Continue with your code if you do.